# Join data match multiple conditions

Tags: r

Df looks like

```
PlateNo  Time   Value
A001     1      3
A001     2      4
A002     1      5
A003     1      6
A001     3      7
```

What i want is something like

```
PlateNo  1  2  3  4
A001     3  4  7  NA
A002     5  NA NA NA
A003     6  NA NA NA
```

Anyone could help?

Comment: What's the point of `Df1` if all information comes from `Df2`?

Comment: all the `*_join` functions from dplyr support multiple columns in the by clause

Comment: could you be more specific @PoGibas

Comment: Something like this should work: `reshape2::dcast(data, PlateNo ~ Time, value.var = "Value")`

Comment: why there is `4` column when it is not present in the `Time` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataF1

ID   TIME  Value
A1    1    27
A1    2    21
A1    3    22
A2    3    32
A2    4    42
A2    5     2
A3    6     2
A3    7    27
A3    8     2


library(tidyr)

DataF2  <- DataF1 %>% spread( ID,Value ,  fill = NA, convert = FALSE)
```

the package tidyr has many functions for data manipulation